Multiple Chrome Profiles when installing Ungoogled-Chromium from ChrLauncher on Windows 11
Browser: Ungoogled-Chromium Version 129.0.6668.104 64 bit
OS: Windows 11 Home Single Language Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
For those who don't know this is Ungoogled Chromium - https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium
I installed Ungoogled Chromium through ChrLauncher
My Chromium installed in Directory "c:\chrlauncher" - the path to chrome.exe is c:\chrlauncher\bin\chrome.exe
Before installing through ChrLauncher, I had an older Ungoogled Chromium build installed manually which I have now uninstalled.
I seem to have 2 different Chromium Profiles on my machine which are different - The visually identifying feature of the 2 profiles is that one has pinkish brown tab colour & the other has a sky blue colour.
If I run chrome directly from c:\chrlauncher\bin\chrome.exe, I get the pink profile. If chrome is automatically started by clicking on some link elsewhere, it starts the blue profile even if the pink browser is already active.
In either of the profiles, I go to Manage profile, i don't see the other profile, which means they may be stored in unrelated places not aware of each other.
How do I fix it to have only profile which is also launched by clicking on links?
UPDATE:
chrome://version/ shows the following profile paths

The blue one shows "C:\Chrlauncher\profile\Profile 1"

The pink one shows "C:\Users\<myuserid>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default"


It looks like the default app for handling links is set to the Blue Profile. How do I change it to the Pink Profile?
Tried deleting everything under c:\chrlauncher\profile. And then clicked on a link in a message, the blue profile opened up again & all directories under c:\chrlauncher\profile seemed to have been recreared.
I have only one chrome.exe in my box, the one in "c:\chrlauncher\bin"

Determine where they are and update your question

What is "they" here? What is where?

They are the Profiles. You need to tell us where the directories for the profiles are located by editing your question. Where is the location on your system.

How do I know where the profiles are located?

Chrome has a settings page for that.

I couldn't find any directory location settings in Chromium Settings. I can find a Customise Profiles settings. But that doesn't contain directory location. In both instances, the Profile is named "Person 1", but in one, Pick a Theme Colour shows a Custom colour (Pinkish Brown), while in the other it shows a blue colour picked. Neither settings shows more than 1 profile. Which means both profiles are unaware of each other

Try chrome://version

Updated the question, thank you

The solution to your dilemma is to delete the Chrome user profile you don’t want. One is the default user which is included with every Chromium based browser. By deleting it your user profile you want to keep will be used by default. If not make sure you switch the system’s default browser to the executable you want to use.

I deleted everything under c:\chrlauncher\profile. And clicked on a link again from a message & directories under profile got recreated & I got a blue chromium. I have only one Chrome.exe, I have uninstalled the older install a few days back.

Fixed it & added an answer which states how. Thank you for your help with this

Looks like SetDefaultBrowser.bat in c:\chrlauncher sets shell open path to chrlauncher.exe rather than chrome.exe
I changed "CHRLAUNCHER_PATH=%~dp0chrlauncher.exe" to
in the batchfile to "CHRLAUNCHER_PATH=%~dp0bin\chrome.exe"
and ran the batch file again. And now clicking on links opens up chrome.exe
I will run chrlauncher.exe manually once in a while to check updates.
